# Parallax in Magento

Tags: magento-enterprise, parallax

I just want to ask if I can do a parallax design inside my magento cms page?
Will there be any conflict when it comes to jquery/javascript codes?

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you do it? Magento like any other website uses HTML, CSS and jQuery. It is no different. You can easily implement parallax effect in Magento. Infact there are hundreds of website built in Magento which uses Parallax.

Regarding jQuery/JavaScript, the conflict is more depended on the jQuery used by you on the website rather than on Magento framework. And yes if there is a conflict it can be resolved.

Comment: why downvote whats wrong with the answer?

Comment: No idea, fixed this :-)